# obtain the manufacturer and product ID and serial number of the display

Tags: linux, hardware, monitors

The goal is to obtain the manufacturer and product ID and the serial number of the display under the Linux platform. I eventually need to get this information in the program in C++. But I also accept the command line acquisition method.

Comment: How is the display connected? Is this for a generic platform where EDID can be expected to be available, or is it for an embedded platform with more specific requirements?

Comment: A display connected via a video output connector or a built-in display. For a generic platform where EDID can be expected to be available

Answer (score 7):

Such information is available via `/sys/class/drm` subsystem. Tools such as `xrandr` use it extensively. Now, specifically there is directory for each display in this subsystem, with a file `edid`, [Extended Display Identification Data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data).

On Debian-based systems there are two packages available, `edid-decode` and `read-edid`. Both seem to work alright, but on old and dated models `read-edid` seems to work well enough, whereas `edid-decode` returns errors:

```
EDID block does NOT conform to EDID 1.3!
    Detailed block string not properly terminated
EDID block does not conform at all!
    Bad year of manufacture
```

So I would recommend installing `read-edid` package. After you have installed, use `parse-edid` command as shown below:

```
$ parse-edid < /sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1/edid 
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "X20G-NagaIII"
    ModelName "X20G-NagaIII"
    VendorName "SPT"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 42 of 2005
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Digital Display
    DisplaySize 410 310
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 30-92
    VertRefresh 40-86
    # Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
```

The other command `get-edid` appears to connect to i2c bus and figures out automatically which displays are connected and what data is available. Now, of course this is no C++ method, but these two tools are likely written in C. Consider looking at their source code and note which libraries they use.

Comment: These two commands really give me some useful information, thank you. But the output I get when I use these two commands has some garbled characters. And there is no product serial number.

Comment: @hxysayhi Sadly, the problem is likely with displays themselves rather than the commands. Displays often expose EDID information either poorly or not compliantly. I do get serial number for either of my two external displays but not internal laptop display. And as Stephen noted, there might be cases where display simply doesn't expose EDID info at all, for example an I2C or SPI display on Raspberry Pi and other embedded systems.  But I'm glad I could help you can find at least some useful information

Comment: What dose the serial number looks like when you parse the edid file? I parse the edid of a  display connected via a video output connector correct, but I didn't get the serial number. The example you gave in the answer does not seem to have a serial number. Can you show me the approximate form of the result  you obtained which with serial number? thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had two Dell U3014 monitors that were nearly identical (no difference in parse-edid output), but I could see different serial numbers when inspecting the edid file for the 5th and 6th Display Port:

```
# Compare edid output
diff -a /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-{5,6}/edid
1c1
PT�K���qO�@�����h��@.`0 6��!�P1V6N45V001L
---
PT�K���qO�@�����h��@.`0 6��!�P1V6N45V002L
4c4
<       ��P� #  �:�q8-@X,E��!�q X,%��!�rQ� n(U��!�
---
>       ��P� #  �:�q8-@X,E��!�q X,%��!�rQ� n(U��!�

# Better view of just serial numbers:
grep -ao 'P1V6N45V00.L' /sys/class/drm/card0-DP-*/edid
/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-5/edid:P1V6N45V001L
/sys/class/drm/card0-DP-6/edid:P1V6N45V002L
```

Also of note is the card0-DP were labeled 1-8, where as in arandr they were listed as 0-7. So to match edid to arandr you subtract one: DP-5=DP-4 and DP-6=DP-5.